# What is correct- Employee Speaks or Employee Speak?

Tags: word-usage, subject-verb-agreement

While making a presentation for my company, I stuck at one header:

> Employee **Speak**

I got confused as I thought that it should be either Employee **Speaks** and there we can show only one employee's testimonial. Or, if we write Employees to include several employees' feedback, we should write 'Employees **Speak**'.

But then, many leading tech companies including [HCL](http://www.hcl.com/employee-speak), [Infosys](https://www.infosys.com/careers/culture/employee-speak/), and others have given Employees' feedback with the title 'Employee Speak'.

Answer (score 1):

For a heading or a title, a noun phrase works better than a sentence.

"Employees speak." is a sentence. It tells us a fact, that employees sometimes make understandable sounds!

"Employee speaks." is also a sentence. But this is worse. News headlines sometimes use this style. It implies that there is some kind of big surprise, as if the employee hasn't spoken for a long time.

"Employee speak" is a noun phrase, but when "speak" is used as a noun it means "jargon" or "Language". This doesn't fit what you want to say.

However the websites you link to don't contain "speak", they show "testimonials" (written statements of recommendation). As a heading I would use "Employee testimonials". This is used [in this context](http://www.calibresys.com/careers2/employee_testimonials.html)

Comment: +1 Since you identify the (likely) possibility that it is a noun phrase. However, I don't know why you would say "speak" as a noun doesn't fit the context. It could be used precisely because they want to imply a shared culture and dialect, as in "friend speak" or "twin speak."

Comment: The context I speak of is the linked websites which feature testimonials, not lists of company jargon.

Comment: I understood that. I'm saying that employees talking about their experiences at the company could be considered "culture-building," and the pages might be labeling themselves using "speak" as a noun in an attempt to give it precisely that spin.

Answer (score 0):

'Employee Speak' does make sense in a certain context but not the one you refer to.  'Employee Speak' sounds like the kind of speech your employees engage in.  I.e., the jargon they use.

'Employees Speak' makes it sound like you've solicited feedback from your employees.  I think this is what you want to use.

'Employee Speaks' sounds odd.  It makes it sound like you have only one employee, or that there is a person named Employee who is speaking.